# NiFi: Need to remove a character from an attribute while leaving all others, but having trouble with the expression

Tags: regex, expression, apache-nifi

I have an attribute that contains URL encoded characters. I need to send it through a URL decode, but for some reason some of the encoded characters have an extra "%" symbol. I added an update attribute to try to fix it, but am having trouble with the expression.

```
Attribute: Name; value: name%c3%a1%s\<first> (NOTE: The length of the string before the "<" is variable.)
```

I need to change it to: `name%c3%a1s\<first>` such that the `%` after the `a1` is removed. I have seen other letters directly before the `"<"`, so I'm not sure how to remove the extra `"%"` but keep the letter. When I run `${Name:urlDecode()}` with the attribute having value `"name%c3%a1s\<first>"` it works, but chokes when the value is `"name%c3%a1%s\<first>"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
${Name:replaceAll('%([a-zA-Z])\b', '$1')}
```

*Details*:

- `%`  - a `%` char
- `([a-zA-Z])` - Group 1: an ASCII letter (you may use `\p{L}` to match any letter)
- `\b` - word boundary.

The replacement is `$1`, the backreference to Group 1 value.